# Calculate the absolute value of the integral $\left | \int_s \vec{F} \vec{dA} \right |$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

We have to calculate the absolute value of

$$\left | \int_s \vec{F}.   \vec{dA} \right |$$ 
of the vector field $F(x,y,z) :=(e^y,0,e^x)  $ on the surface 
$$S:=\left \{ (x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=25, 0≤z≤2, x≥0, y≥0 \right \}$$

**solution i tried**-The given vector field is $F(x,y,z) :=(e^y,0,e^x)  $ and we know form Gauss's Theorem that $$\int_s \vec{F}.   \vec{dA}=\int_v  \nabla.\vec{F}dv$$ now according to this if  calculate the divergence of my given field vector it will be zero 
$$\vec{\nabla}.(e^y,0,e^x)=0$$ so the answer will be zero .But there is some non zero number in answer ,is there something that i'm missing ?

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: Gauss’ theorem only applies to *closed*, outwardly oriented surfaces. Is your surface closed?

Comment: can you please tell me what kind of surface  $S$  will represent? i am confused now

Comment: If you’re unfamiliar with this surface, you can determine the shape of $x^2+y^2=25$ by considering level curves or cross sections. Once you know what it looks like in general, you can then take the bounds $0\leq z\leq 2, x,y\geq 0$ into consideration to see which portion of the surface you are integrating over.